# iOS - Labels and Images not setted

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS application and I have a strange problem.

The application sends local notifications to the user and when he taps on it, my app programmatically chooses a ViewController, sets its labels and images and then displays it to the user. But it simply doesn't work! Labels and images are not set. Here's my code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void) manageLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *) notification  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];

    if ([self.theme intValue] == 1) {
        ADATheme1ViewController *notifyViewController = [[ADATheme1ViewController alloc] init];
        [notifyViewController.titleLabel setText:self.title];
        [notifyViewController.bodyLabel setText:self.text];
        [notifyViewController.bgImage setImage: [self getImageFromURL:self.background]];
        self.window.rootViewController = notifyViewController;
    } else {
        ADATheme2ViewController *notifyViewController = [[ADATheme2ViewController alloc] init];
        [notifyViewController.titleLabel setText:self.title];
        [notifyViewController.bodyLabel setText:self.text];
        [notifyViewController.offerLabel setText:self.offer];
        [notifyViewController.bgImage setImage: [self getImageFromURL:self.background]];
        self.window.rootViewController = notifyViewController;
    }
}
```

I made some debugging and my properties (text, title, offer and so on) are properly set. The method getImageFromUrl: returns an UIImage* and it works.
My ViewControllers are very simple, here's the code (but nothing special)

.h file
    #import

```
@interface ADATheme1ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bgImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bodyLabel;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ADATheme1ViewController.h"

@interface ADATheme1ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ADATheme1ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


@end
```

and there's a .xib file attached.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you connected these IBOutlet properties to xib ? If you have, try to initialize the view controller with `ADATheme1ViewController *notifyViewController = [[ADATheme1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`.

Comment: @KudoCC yes, I have connected the IBOutlets to the xib. I have tried your solution, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: After initialize the view controller, access its view using viewcontroler.view to force xib to be loaded. `ADATheme1ViewController *notifyViewController = [[ADATheme1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; notifyViewController.view ;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the view weren't loaded so the properties were set to nil.

I added just a line of code to "force" the loading of my view before setting labels:

```
[notifyViewController view];
```

Comment: You can also set your rootController before assigning the labels values.